# How to move Audio Tag background animation

Tags: html, css

how can i make the webkit-media-controls-timeline background stripes moving?
i've try this on different browsers, the background still freezing.why?

```css
#theAudio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
background-image: linear-gradient(-44deg, #F7BD4C 25%, #f1f1f1 25%, #f1f1f1 50%, #F7BD4C 50%, #F7BD4C 74.9%, #f1f1f1 74.9%, #f1f1f1 44%);
animation: progress-bar-stripes 3s linear infinite!important;
background-size: 38px 38px;
height:7px;
border-radius: 36px!important;}
      @keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
      from {background-position: 0 0;}
      to {background-position: 40px 0;}}
```

```html
    <audio id="theAudio" controls>
      <source src="http://audio.ngfiles.com/551000/551191_Pressure.mp3" type="audio/ogg">
      <source src="http://audio.ngfiles.com/551000/551191_Pressure.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
      Your browser does not support the audio tag.
    </audio>
```

Comment: can someone help me out, or maybe ill just stick with freezing background stripes.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but webkit is a rendering engine used only by Safari and Chrome until a certain version.Anyway, did you try `@-webkit-keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 40px 0;
    }
}` ?

Comment: thanks, it dint work i have tried -o- ,-moz, -webkit- ,maybe you are right it only used on Chrome & Safari

Comment: Pseudo-element selectors `::-webkit-media-controls-timeline` are not animatable